# ios incompatible pointer types assigning to NSError _strong from NSError _autoreleasing

Tags: objective-c, nserror

I'm getting this error:

```
incompatible pointer types assigning to NSError _strong from NSError _autoreleasing
```

here is my header file:

```
@interface myClass : NSObject

{
    NSError *errorPointer;
}
```

This is my implementation file:

```
- (id)initWithError:(NSError **)error
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        errorPointer = error; // <-- here is where I'm getting the error
    }
    return self;
}
```

any of you knows why or how can I fix this error?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(NSError **)error should be (NSError *)error

Comment: Can you elaborate why that's the case, or when that became the case, because every example everywhere that I can find says to use (NSError **)

Comment: @LogicsaurusRex NSError** is used when you want to return an (usually optional) value from a function. If NSError is a normal incoming object (rare but possible), NSError* is used.